# Strange change in rabbit's behaviour

Tags: behavior, health, rabbits, fear, veterinarian

I have a bunny who is almost 6 months old. When I first got him home at the age of 2-3 months, I tried not to scare him and to let him explore the surroundings. Everything was fine until I wanted to put him into the cage for the night. The moment I did it, he started fighting and everything was like that for a month or two when I stopped putting him in the cage for the night and instead I started letting him on the balcony. During these months he was constantly demanding head rubs, running around my feet in circles, binkying and laying down absolutely everywhere, especially on my bed. I loved the fact that he looked like he trusted me staying on my bed and following me everywhere. The only problem was that he started peeing everywhere to mark his territory I think, mainly on the parts of my bed he was not staying on.

Finally I decided to take him to the vet and eventually emasculate him so I made an appointment. The vet agreed to do the procedure, but my bunny looked so scared. He was trembling and biting me when I tried to pet him. After the procedure we took him home and waited for the effects of the anesthesia to fade away in a few hours, but it wasn’t like that. He seemed off for 2  days... he was not eating his favourite food nor drinking water, his poops were smaller than usual and he was lacking energy.

After googling I came to the conclusion that I had to take him to the vet, but my father insisted to wait a few more days and both of us looked carefully at what he was eating and we also gave him food and little by little he started eating and drinking water and of course his poops finally got to their normal size. I was relieved and he seemed to be alright because he started again to run around my feet, but this time he was doing it for no more that 2 times a day and he also refused staying on my bed and he was hiding in order to lay down and things have been like that for the past three weeks, I think, and I don’t know what I did wrong.

Also, he used to enjoy being chased but now he just seems to be scared and I don't know what to do to make him feel safe again and love me. I want him to live a good life, but at the moment I am afraid he might be depressed, thing that I don’t want to be true. What is more, I did not spend so much time with him lately and I am wondering if it might be from this?

Comment: Hello Bianca, welcome to pets.SE You have a lots of informations. this is a good point. but it is a little bit confusing because you have no clear question in it. please re-think the situation and ask one question :) if you have more than one question, you are allowed to do a seperate post for each question.

Comment: at first reading: neutering do not solve the bed-peeing issue. balcony depends at the climate, but big changes in temperature between indoor and outdoor are bad. everytime ask a vet for urgent health questions and not strangers from the internet. catch and carry rabbits is for them terrible, until they are common with it. this could be the main reason for the new shy-ness. they connect carrying only with predators until humans teach them otherwise. spend your time to teach him with a lots of treats (food and grooming).

Comment: shy after handling: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28094/bunny-shies-away-from-me-after-moving-him-is-he-traumatized-what-can-i-do bed-peeing: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23250/bunny-pees-on-bed toilet-training: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-required-to-house-break-a-rabbit

Answer (score 2):

First of all, keep in mind that it's a good thing for him (and for your comfort) to have been sterilized. He should live longer and be way more calm. Also, a bunny can take one week to recover fully from an anesthesia. This is a little body against a big chemical product so don't worry.

My guess here is that he doesn't have the loads of hormones coming through his body anymore, making him more calm. Also, bunnies are very intelligent, and maybe he is a bit mad at you. The fact that you didn't have much time with him the last past day is important too.

I don't know if he have a lot of toys, but if he used to be playful, you can do a bucket with a lot of bunny toys inside where he can come and take the one he wants. It's also a very good thing for his teeth as he will certainly chew on it.

Lastly, I wouldn't recommend to let him on the balcony. Bunnies are fragile so he could easily get sick. To avoid the cage, you can find some adaptable enclosure with no roof that is more adapted to bunnies. You need to stimulate him, and stay close to him. But if he is hiding in order to sleep, it's just because he wants to be quiet / alone.

However, if you still have doubt on his health state, never hesitate to consult a vet. As I said, bunnies are fragile, they can hide something and you will know to late, or he is just fine and the vet will reassure you.

As long as he eats and drinks, I would say that there is no much worry to have. In my experience, depressed bunnies basically let themselves die.